# Google admod policy

Tags: android, youtube, google-play

I am a newbie in android programming. I build the first app and want to publish on google play (intergrated admod ads). In my app, I use youtube api to play videos from youtube url. I have 2 questions
First: In playlist image, I downloaded image from this link: img.youtube.com/vi/videoId/0.jpg. I didn't know that using this image from this link (downloaded) is illegal or not. 
Second: Could I place ads in the same layout with youtube player (its more space in there). I don't know if it violates google policy or not.
I am so scared that my app will be ban. Give me an advice. Thank you so much

Comment: Google next time, https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html

Comment: I had google it. But there is no information about policy when I put ads on apps has youtube API. Is it violated?